# How do I return the result from a RecyclerView adaptor back to the MainActvity.kt?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How do I return the result of the position from my Recyclerview Adapter, back to the
MainActivity.kt?

Any help on how to achieve this in Kotlin would be really appreciated!

Thanks

**Adapter.kt**

```
     class UsersAdapter(
      private val users: ArrayList<User>
      ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.DataViewHolder>() {
  class DataViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
      fun bind(user: User) {
          itemView.textViewUserName.text = user.name
          Glide.with(itemView.imageViewAvatar.context)
            .load(user.avatar)
                .into(itemView.imageViewAvatar)
      }
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
          DataViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                        R.layout.item_layout, parent,
                        false
                )
          )
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = Int.MAX_VALUE
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val pos = position % users.size
        holder.bind(users[pos])        // bind the actual item
        Log.d(Constraints.TAG, " onBindViewHolder:" + pos)
     }
     }
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
     class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     lateinit var adapter: ConcatAdapter
     lateinit var userVerticalAdapter: UsersAdapter
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setupDataInRecyclerView()
     }
     private fun setupDataInRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, 
                   false)
        userVerticalAdapter = UsersAdapter(DataSource.getUser())
        val listOfAdapters = listOf(userVerticalAdapter)
        adapter = ConcatAdapter(listOfAdapters)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(Int.MAX_VALUE/2)
        ItemSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
     }
```

Comment: Use an interface, or an abstract, or a static reference. I recommend learning Kotlin or Java basics before developing an app.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add callback to your adapter -

```
lateinit var listener: OnItemClickListener

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun getAdapterPosition(position : Int )
}

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
    this.listener= listener
}
```

Call listener's method form where you want to get value of quantity as below -

```
 listener?.getAdapterPosition(pos)
```

Implement this listener in your activity -

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RecycleViewCartAdapter 
.OnItemClickListener  {

override
public fun getAdapterPosition(position : Int ){
// required value is in the position variable

}
}
```

Add below line above setAdapter method

```
 adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)
 recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: Hi – really appreciate the help! I am still struggling a bit: when I add “adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)” I get an “Unresolved reference”? The adapter class has setOnItemClickListener is there, so what could be the problem please? Cheers

Comment: Just need to add public as I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Have made it public but still the same problem - still get “Unresolved reference”? Cheers

Comment: have you created method named setOnItemClickListener in your adapter as mentioned above or not

Comment: Thanks. I still can't spot the problem :-(.  I have posted a new thread (have spent hours trying to get the updated on here but failed), with the latest code - would you be able to have a quick look at it please - many thanks.  It's on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657820/return-the-result-from-a-recyclerview-adaptor-back-to-the-mainactvity-kt

Comment: You have not implemented interface in your class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RecycleViewCartAdapter.OnItemClickListener . Here is the problem mate.