# Return the result from a RecyclerView adaptor back to the MainActvity.kt?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying do I return the result of the position from my Recyclerview Adapter, but I can't call  the      " adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)" from  MainActivity.kt? I get the error "Unresolved reference: setOnItemClickListener"?

I've had to post a new thread as I can't get all the code to be shown - after taking quite a few hours failing on this I am losing the will to live :-(

**Adapter.kt**

```
  class UsersAdapter(
    private val users: ArrayList<User>
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.DataViewHolder>() {
  class DataViewHolder(itemView: View) : 
          RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(user: User) {
        itemView.textViewUserName.text = user.name
        Glide.with(itemView.imageViewAvatar.context)
            .load(user.avatar)
                .into(itemView.imageViewAvatar)
    }
 }
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        DataViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                        R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)             
        )
override fun getItemCount(): Int = Int.MAX_VALUE
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataViewHolder, position: Int){ 
    val pos = position % users.size
    holder.bind(users[pos])        
    Log.d(Constraints.TAG, "onBindViewHolder:" + pos)
}
lateinit var listener: OnItemClickListener
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun getAdapterPosition(position : Int )
}
public fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
    this.listener= listener
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var adapter: ConcatAdapter
lateinit var userVerticalAdapter: UsersAdapter
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setupDataInRecyclerView()
}
//override
public fun getAdapterPosition(position : Int ){
    // required value is in the position variable
    Log.d(Constraints.TAG, "This is where it is going!" )
}
private fun setupDataInRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, 
              LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    userVerticalAdapter = UsersAdapter(DataSource.getUser())
    val listOfAdapters = listOf(userVerticalAdapter)
    adapter = ConcatAdapter(listOfAdapters)
    //This errors with "Unresolved reference: setOnItemClickListener"
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(Int.MAX_VALUE/2)
    ItemSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
}
public fun ShowWhatRecieved(isitthere: Int){
    ShowMeIt.text = isitthere.toString()}
}
```

**Revised and Updated MainActvity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), UsersAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
lateinit var adapter: ConcatAdapter
lateinit var userVerticalAdapter: UsersAdapter
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setupDataInRecyclerView()
}

override public fun getAdapterPosition(position : Int ){
    Log.d(Constraints.TAG, "This is where it is going!" )
}

private fun setupDataInRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    userVerticalAdapter = UsersAdapter(DataSource.getUser())
    val listOfAdapters = listOf(userVerticalAdapter)
    adapter = ConcatAdapter(listOfAdapters)
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(Int.MAX_VALUE/2)
    ItemSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
}
public fun ShowWhatRecieved(isitthere: Int){
    ShowMeIt.text = isitthere.toString()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `this` as argument it will pass the context but in the parameter of function `setOnItemClickListener` in adapter you have defined listener of `OnItemClickListener` type. So you need to pass the argument of `OnItemClickListener` type.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the `OnItemClickListener` at your activity and you will be able to use `this` keyword. But you also can make an anonymous implementation of `OnItemClickListener` interface when you try to send.

But I would prefer the option 1. To implement the `OnItemClickListener` to your activity, implement all methods of that interface and than you can use `this` keyword when you need to pass `OnItemClickListener` anywhere in that class.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve added “class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), UsersAdapter.OnItemClickListener {…” as suggested but still get the “Unresolved reference” on “adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)” error? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented interface in your as below -

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RecycleViewCartAdapter.OnItemClickListener
```

Here is the problem mate.

Comment: Many thanks…Nearly there…I think.  I’ve added “class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), UsersAdapter.OnItemClickListener {…“ and made “override” to “public fun getAdapterPosition” …but I still get the “Unresolved reference” on “adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this)”. I must be missing 

Comment: Do clean your project. And try again.

Comment: I did the Build->Clean Project....still has the same error? Cheers

Comment: Thanks,, I've put in the main thread at the end. Cheers

Comment: You have declared lateinit var userVerticalAdapter: UsersAdapter and lateinit var adapter: ConcatAdapter, but you are using adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this) . You have declared setOnItemClickListener() method in UsersAdapter not in ConcatAdapter.

Comment: Sorry – I’m still struggling with this one .  I’m not certain of how to correct the UsersAdapter/ConcatAdapter problem?  Really appreciate the help

Comment: Its simple dear, You have defined interface in different class and using it with different class. Replace adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this) with userVerticalAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this). Your error will disappear.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve changed that but I’m still getting the same error, plus an “unresolved reference” on “UsersAdapter.OnItemClickListener“ in the MainActivity class? Many thanks for all the help!

Comment: its userVerticalAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this) not “UsersAdapter.OnItemClickListener“

Comment: Thanks - I’ve now got it running but when I run it I can’t see anything arrive at either ShowWhatRecieved or getAdapterPosition - I have placed Log.d on both but aren’t called, whereas the Log.d in onBindViewHolde shown as expected? Cheers

Comment: You need to add listener.getAdapterPosition(pos)in onBindViewHolder method. You will have your position value in the getAdapterPosition  in the activity.

Comment: BRILLIANT! WORKING! MANY MANY THANKS!

Comment: Kindly accept and upvote the answer as it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Despite all your effort by creating an interface and implementing it inside your recycler-view, I suggest you use lambda instead of interface since you are writing Kotlin, and writing a lambda instead of an interface is a cleaner approach in Kotlin for ClickListener.

Create a lambda parameter both for your adapter and your viewholder. since you want to pass the position of a clicked item so your lambda must have an `Int` input and nothing as output so it would look like this: `listener: (Int) -> Unit`.

The rest of your code would be something like this, you get the idea I just edited important parts:

```
class UsersAdapter(private val users : ArrayList<CrashlyticsReport.Session.User>,
                   private val listener : (Int) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.DataViewHolder>() {
    
    class DataViewHolder(itemView : View, private val listener : (Int) -> Unit) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener { listener(adapterPosition) }
        }
        
        fun bind(user : CrashlyticsReport.Session.User) {
            itemView.textViewUserName.text = user.name
            Glide.with(itemView.imageViewAvatar.context).load(user.avatar).into(itemView.imageViewAvatar)
        }
    }
}
```

then in your activity you can write:

```
userVerticalAdapter = UsersAdapter(DataSource.getUser()) {
//clicklistener event here
}
```

or:

```
userVerticalAdapter = UsersAdapter(DataSource.getUser(),this::ShowWhatRecieved)
```

also since you're using `ConcatAdapter` it's better to use `bindingAdapterPosition` instead of `adapterPosition`.

Comment: Many thanks. I think I’m getting some progress! I’m struggling now with my adapter: “DataViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false))”  says “No value passed…”. Any help really appreciate - thanks